# Update Symfony parent entity timestampable field when child entity persisted on database

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I am working with two entities, a Shopping Cart and the lines of the Cart.

Both of them are using timestampable behavior of Doctrine. The point is that I need that the Cart change the updatedAt field when I add or remove units from a CartLine Entity. At the moment, only updates when I add or remove a line from the cart.

Class Cart:

```
class Cart {
...
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(
         targetEntity="CartLine", 
         mappedBy="cart", 
         cascade={"all"}, 
         orphanRemoval=true
       )
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"free" = "ASC", "id" = "ASC"})
     */
    protected $lines;
```

Class CartLine:

```
class CartLine {
    ....
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(
         targetEntity="Cart", 
         inversedBy="lines",
         cascade={"all"}
       )
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(
         name="cart_id", 
         referencedColumnName="id"
        )
     */
    protected $cart;
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

you can use an event listner on your CartLine and on PostPersist update your Cart

Comment: Thank you, I have already working towards this direction, but, I think that I could do it using doctrine annotations (like `orphan removal`) defined in the entity.